# How can i calculate points perpendicular to a line

Tags: math

I have two points PointA and Point B denoted by red points.

[image]

i can calculate the Perpendicaular points denoted by green points ( Top Perpendicular point , Bottom Perpendicular point) when the line is horizontal.

When line has a slope how would i calculate the perpendicular points.

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with rotations about a point?One thing you can do is to add +- y_margin just as you were most likely doing in the horizontal case. but then rotate the resultant points about the endpoint by an angle that the line makes with the horizontal. 

Another solution is to calculate a perpendicular vector to the line, and add that as much of that vector to the end-point as you desire.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a programming question

Comment: @talonmies it is a programming question , i need help in maths for my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate direction vector of AB

```
dx = b.x-a.x
dy = b.y-a.y
```

Normalize it (make unit length)

```
len = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
udx = dx / len
udy = dy / len
```

Make perpendicular vector

```
px = -udy
py = udx
```

Calculate green points

```
g1.x = b.x + px*distance
g1.y = b.y + py*distance

g2.x = b.x - px*distance
g2.y = b.y - py*distance
```

Comment: Copy-paste mistake, corrected. But we can exclude px, py, using substitution in formula like `g1.x = b.x  - udy*distance`

Comment: When I read `px = -udy
py = udx`, I immediately understand that you are taking a perpendicular vector. If I read `g1.x = b.x  - udy*distance` directly I have to spend a lot of time figuring out why `x` is mixed up with `y` and why there is a minus sign. I think keeping `px` and `py` is better, unless you add comments to explain what is going on.